# How can I calculate the determinant of this type of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given the matrix

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
a&b&c&d\\
a^{2}&b^{2}&c^{2}&d^{2}\\
a^{3}&b^{3}&c^{3}&d^{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How can I prove that $\det(A)=(d-c)(d-b)(d-a)(c-b)(c-a)(b-a)$ ?

And as a second question, what is the general formula for this type of matrix and how can I prove i?

---

I'm quite certain (though I could be wrong) that the general formula is as follows:

$$
\det(
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\dots&1\\
a_{1}&\dots&a_{n}\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
a_{1}^{n-1}&\dots&a_{n}^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
) = \prod_{i>j}(a_{i}-a_{j})
$$
It definitely out for $n\leq4$.

---

I have tried a proof by induction over $n$. It's easy to prove that it holds for $n=1$:

$$
\det(\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix})=1\ \checkmark
$$

For the inductive step, I've tried using row reduction on the last row and got to this:

$$
\det(
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\dots&1\\
a_{1}&\dots&a_{n+1}\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
a_{1}^{n}&\dots&a_{n+1}^{n}
\end{bmatrix}
) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+k+1}\prod_{\begin{align}i&>j\\i,j&\neq k\end{align}}(a_{i}-a_{j})
$$

but I can't figure out how to prove that equals $\prod_{i>j}(a_{i}-a_{j})$. Is there a way to prove this. And if not, how should I go about solving this exercise?

<sub>If some of the mathematical notation I used is incorrect or very unusual,
 I would also appreciate it if that was pointed out to me.</sub>

Comment: start by reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix